# Extract numbers and make a double from a string

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0

I have strings and I need to make doubles from them.  They're all in format:

```
"Blabla 11/moreBla 17-18"  That should become 11.1718
"Blabla 7/moreBla 8-9" --> 7.89
"Blabla 4/moreBla 6-8" --> 4.68
```

etc.

There could also be extra spaces or dash could be a forward slash. So, anything like that:

```
"Blabla 11/moreBla 17-18"
"Blabla 11 / moreBla 17-18"
"Blabla 11/moreBla 17/18"
"Blabla 11/moreBla 17 / 18"
"Blabla 11 / moreBla 17 / 18"
```

I tried splitting the string first, but then apparently there are all these other cases.  So split isn't working well here.  Maybe RegEx could be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "Blabla 11/moreBla 17-18";
        string[] s = input.Split('/');
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s[0], @"[^\d]", "") + "." + Regex.Replace(s[1], @"[^\d]", "")); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11.1718
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/vk936).

---

Or this code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 class Program
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         string input = "Blabla 11/moreBla 17-18";
         string[] s = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d\/]", "").Split('/');
         Console.WriteLine(s[0] + "." + s[1]);
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
11.1718
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/MyVXC).

Comment: Thank you. The Replace example is what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the test cases you gave in your question:

```
string input = @"Blabla 11/moreBla 17/18";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, "(\\d+)");
double val = Convert.ToDouble(matches[0].Value + "." + matches[1].Value + matches[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\d+).+?(\d+).+?(\d+)
```

replace it with

```
\1.\2\3
```

Basically it matches the first group of digits and put it to the integer part, then it matches the second and the third group of digits, no matter what is between them, and makes the decimal part.

The c# code would be

```
public double MatchNumber(string input){
    Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+).+?(\d+).+?(\d+)");
    Match match = r.Match(input);
    if (match.Success){
        return Convert.toDouble(
             match.Groups[1].Value+"."+
             match.Groups[2].Value+
             match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like this

```
String data = "Blabla 11/moreBla 17-18";
data = Regex.Replace(DATA, "[a-zA-Z ]", "");

data = String.Concat(DATA.Split('/')[0], "." , Regex.Replace(DATA.Split('/')[1], "(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)",""));

double MyValue = Convert.ToDouble(data);
```

Hope this will help.